# Do "Leave Closed" votes in Reopen queue count as voting once in the "Close" direction?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-reopen

An individual user may only vote once in each direction (close, reopen) on a given question.

Does a "Leave Closed" vote in the Reopen queue count as a close vote for purposes of determining whether a user can vote to close this question in the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is not a close vote. It is a review action. It would not prevent you from voting to close the question in the future if it were ever reopened.