# Approve and leave closed, review again in reopen queue

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, vote-to-reopen

In the suggested edit review queue [I voted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/227729) to *Approve and leave closed*, while another reviewer voted *Approve and reopen*. The other reviewer's action sent the post to the Reopen queue, which is by design as per the [announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) for the review queues:

> It takes two approve votes (any combination of Approve and reopen or
> Approve and leave closed) to remove the task out of the Suggested
> Edits queue. If at least one of the votes is Approve and reopen, a new
> task will be created in the Reopen votes queue.

When I checked the Reopen review queue afterwards I was able to [vote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/227742) on the same post:

[image]

This seems to violate the idea that you should not be able to perform the same vote (i.e., leave closed) on the same post twice. This is related to [Do "Leave Closed" votes in Reopen queue count as voting once in the "Close" direction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239098/do-leave-closed-votes-in-reopen-queue-count-as-voting-once-in-the-close-dire) but it is not the same, in that question one vote is from a queue whereas the other vote is directly on the post while in the current case  both "leave closed" votes are from a queue, just from two different queues. Effectively this means that I can override the other reviewer's approve and reopen vote, although they could presumably also vote to reopen from the reopen queue again, meaning that a part of the review process intended for four people is effectively performed by two people.

Question: is this by design, and is this setup desirable? Would it be better to skip the post in the reopen queue if you have also voted for this post in the suggested edit queue with respect to reopening? Note that this is not about voting on the same post to only approve a normal, non-"submit for review" edit and subsequently vote for this post again if it ends up in the reopen queue for another reason.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is how it works between the close and reopen queues too. You can make the same decision on the same post in both (since status-quo votes such as "leave closed" don't actually include casting a vote).

Comment: @Laurel does that mean that "Approve and leave open" does not allow you to subsequently vote in the Reopen queue (as that presumably is a real vote)? That would make it even worse in terms of voting balance when one person wants the post closed and the other wants it open.

Comment: There is no "approve and *leave* open". While I'm not so familiar with this new feature, I don't think that "approve and reopen" actually casts a reopen vote, so they could probably review in the reopen queue. Either way, it is their privilege (if they have enough rep) to cast a reopen vote on the question if they haven't already, which is functionally the same no matter where they do it. I know that the submit to review checkbox itself doesn't cast a reopen vote, even when it's someone who could vote (which is a nice hack for mods but kinda confusing overall).

Comment: I see, so the suggested edit review is just to put a post in the reopen queue or not but does not actually cast a vote either way. That seems to be a bad use of reviewer effort, given that the reviewer in the suggested edit queue knows how they want to vote regarding reopening, in fact they have already done so but it didn't count. On TeX.SE that's not a problem as the queues are mostly empty, but on other sites I would think this can be smarter by propagating the vote into the next queue.